# Laravel 4 Form::open set action

Tags: php, action, laravel, forms, laravel-4

I'm currently trying out Laravel 4 and I have created a resource controller. In the 'edit' function I'm building a form, which should post to the 'update' function.

To create the form open tag I use the `Form::open()` function which recently got added to Laravel 4 it seems.
But when I just do `Form::open()` the action of the form is the current url and I can't figure out how to change the action.

I tried `Form::open('clients/' . $client->id)` but this gives me the following error:

**ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder::open() must be of the type array**

So I tried `Form::open('[clients/' . $client->id)`. This doesn't generate an error, but now the form open tag is:

`<form method="POST" action="http://boekhouding.dev/clients/1/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8" clients/1="clients/1">`

And I also tried it like this: `Form::open(['action' => 'clients/' . $client->id])` but when I do it like this, the form open tag has no action at all.

So, does anyone know how to set the form action? Using a named route would be perfect, but even being able to set the action at all would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use named route, controller action or simple url to set form action.

To set it via named route use:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('route_name', $client->id))) }}
```

To set it via controller action use:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('ClientController@update', $client->id))) }}
```

So the **keyword `action`** does not reffer to 'action' parameter of form tag, but to **controller action**

And you can also use plain URL like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'someurl')) }}
```

Comment: what about to set the form action on itself?

Comment: Basic, make sure the route is named in the routes.php: {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'route_name')) }}

Answer (score 1):

@jeffrey_way tweeted about improving the new FormBuilder in Laravel 4. The following paste bucket link should help. It seems to be more about RESTful controllers, but relavant.

[Form action sensible defaults - paste bucket](http://paste.laravel.com/ky1)

I thought I read something about him coming out with a Forms tutorial tomorrow. If so, it might be found here [net.tutsplus.com/?s=laravel](http://net.tutsplus.com/?s=laravel)