# Laravel / Blade - is it possible to echo a variable into the parameter of a function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to use the same form code for both my Create and Update forms. I am using the following Blade function from Laravel's Form Helper:

```
{!! Form::model($MyObject, ['action' => '{{ $action }}']) !!}
```

If you see I'm echoing `{{ $action }}` into the `action` parameter, so it can be dynamic. But Laravel throws

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 561:
>
> Action App\Http\Controllers\<?php echo e($action); ?> not defined. (View: > /path/to/project/folder/resources/views/baz.blade.php)

error whenever I do this. If I try doing the following:

```
{!! Form::model($MyObject, ['action' => $action]) !!}
```

Then the outputted Form tag looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://mysite.app/mycontroller/%7Bmycontroller%7D" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

And submitting the form throws MethodNotAllowed.

This is how my controller functions are set up:

```
public function create()
{
    $view_data = [
        'type'      => 'Create',
        'action'    => 'MyController@create',
        'my_object' => new MyObject
    ];

    return view('myviews.form', $view_data);
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $view_data = [
        'type'      => 'Edit',
        'action'    => 'MyController@update',
        'my_object' => MyObject::find($id)
    ];

    return view('myviews.form', $view_data);
}
```

But Laravel just throws errors. I can't find any way to pass a variable into a parameter in a Blade tag. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why wont `{!! Form::model($MyObject, ['action' => $action]) !!}` work?

Comment: You are 'echoing' value to array. You don't need to echo a variable to make it dynamic.

Comment: @Schlaus It will work because that's the correct way to do it

Comment: That's what I thought but it then outputs this as the action: `<form method="POST" action="http://mysite/mycontroller/%7Bmycontroller%7D" accept-charset="UTF-8">`...

Comment: I think this is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450303/laravel-4-formopen-set-action

Answer (score 2):

Just use the variable directly:

`{!! Form::model($MyObject, ['action' => $action]) !!}`

Comment: But now it just outputs this: `<form method="POST" action="http://mysite/mycontroller/%7Bmycontroller%7D" accept-charset="UTF-8">`...

Comment: @Jack Can u `{{dd($action)}}` before the form? Seems like the variable is null

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450303/laravel-4-formopen-set-action

You could also try an alternative approach and set `$view_data['action'] = action('MyController@create', $extra_params_as_needed);` which you can read more about at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls